# After restoring dump in postgres some primary keys are missing

Tags: postgresql

After dumping a database using pg_dump like so:

```
pg_dump --verbose --host=<host> --username=<user> -W --encoding=UTF-8 -j 10 --file=dump_bak  --format=d --dbname=<database>
```

and trying to reimport it with:

```
pg_restore -d <database> --host=<host> -n public --username=<user> -W --exit-on-error --format=d -j 10 --verbose dump_bak
```

…we are missing some of our Primary Keys. It looks like a few have been restored, but not all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any error messages during the restore process?

Comment: Are they missing in all tables, in several tables, or in a single table?

Comment: There were no error messages during restore. And they are missing in most tables, but not in all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Postgres is a bit buggy there concerning existing connections. We have found a workaround:

Dump it with:

```
pg_dump --verbose --host=<dbhost> --username=<username> --encoding=UTF-8 --file=<dumpfile> --format=d --jobs=10 --dbname=<dbname>
```

Restore it with:

```
export PGPASSWORD="<pwd>"

#prevent new connections, kill existing connections
sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/psql -q -c "update pg_database set datallowconn = 'false' where datname = '<dbname>'; SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = '<dbname>';"

#kick db
sudo -u postgres dropdb <dbname>

#recreate it
sudo -u postgres createdb <dbname>

#allow connections again
sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/psql -q -c "update pg_database set datallowconn = 'true' where datname = '<dbname>';"

#import data from dump
pg_restore --verbose -d <dbname> --host=$1 --username=<username> -j 4 <dumplocation>
```